# Class views in Django, Html not showing

Tags: python, html, django

I'm confused with why my HTML template is not showing up.

I'm trying to learn Class base views instead of functions on Django.

I know the URL is working because {% extend base.html %} is showing, but anything else like the h1 tags aren't showing up in the render?

Can anyone help please.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import (
    CreateView,
    DetailView,
    ListView,
    UpdateView,
    ListView,
    DeleteView
)

from .models import Article

class ArticleListView(ListView):

    template_name = 'article/article_list.html'
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
```

url.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    ArticleListView
)
app_name = 'article'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name = 'article_list'),
```

article_list.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}


<h1> Test </h1>
<h1> Test </h1>
{%block content%}
{% for instance in object_list %}

    <p>{{instance.id}} - <a href = '{{instance.get_absolute_url}}'> {{instance.title}} </a></p>

{%endfor%}
{%endblock%}

[This is the outcome when i request get html, The current html is coming from base.html][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W09EE.png
```

Comment: you have to put those `h` tag  inside your block in order to render and display them

Comment: Hi beer44, i tryed that. Its still not rendering anything but html from base.html

Comment: Show your base.html template.

Comment: I think it was something wrong with Django. I have since delete all tables and reseted everything and migrated.  Now it seems to be working again. >.<  @DanielRoseman thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in the view:

```
context_object_name = 'article'
model = models. Article
```

And use this is in the template:

```
article. Id 
{{article.get_absolute_url}}
```